# Is this the most efficient way of checking if if this value is empty?

Tags: php, mysql

I am running a query against our Rates Table and as you can see. If the value comes back empty. It checks Again and just does this over and over using different use cases. I am just wanting to make sure that this the most efficient way of checking this.

```
$rates = Rates::find()->where("status_active = 'active' AND master_account = '$account' AND branch_id = '$branch' AND location_from = '$location_from_id' AND location_to = '$location_to_id' AND CAST('$order_placed_time' AS time) BETWEEN book_from AND book_by")->all();        
        
if(empty($rates))
{
    //IF THERE IS MASTER, NO BRANCH, YES LOCATION
    $rates = Rates::find()->where("status_active = 'active' AND master_account = '$account' AND branch_id = '-1' AND location_from = '$location_from_id' AND location_to = '$location_to_id' AND CAST('$order_placed_time' AS time) BETWEEN book_from AND book_by")->all();
    if($region_from_id !='' && $region_to_id !='')
    {
                
        if(empty($rates)) { // IF RESTRICTED IS PICKUP
            $rates = Rates::find()->where("status_active = 'active' AND master_account = '$account' AND branch_id = '$branch' AND region_from = '$region_from_id' AND region_to =   '$region_to_id' AND restricted = '1' AND restricted_location_id = '$location_from_id' AND CAST('$order_placed_time' AS time) BETWEEN book_from AND book_by")->all();
        }
        if(empty($rates)) { // IF RESTRICTED IS DELIVERY
            $rates = Rates::find()->where("status_active = 'active' AND master_account = '$account' AND branch_id = '$branch' AND region_from = '$region_from_id' AND region_to =   '$region_to_id' AND restricted = '2' AND restricted_location_id = '$location_to_id' AND CAST('$order_placed_time' AS time) BETWEEN book_from AND book_by")->all();
        }
        if(empty($rates)) {
            // IF THERE IS NO RESTRICTION
            $rates = Rates::find()->where("status_active = 'active' AND master_account = '$account' AND branch_id = '$branch' AND region_from = '$region_from_id' AND region_to =   '$region_to_id' AND restricted = '0' AND CAST('$order_placed_time' AS time) BETWEEN book_from AND book_by")->all();
        }

        if(empty($rates)) { // IF RESTRICTED IS PICKUP
            $rates = Rates::find()->where("status_active = 'active' AND master_account = '$account' AND branch_id = '-1' AND region_from = '$region_from_id' AND region_to = '$region_to_id' AND restricted = '1' AND restricted_location_id = '$location_from_id' AND CAST('$order_placed_time' AS time) BETWEEN book_from AND book_by")->all();
        }
        if(empty($rates)) { // IF RESTRICTED IS DELIVERY
            $rates = Rates::find()->where("status_active = 'active' AND master_account = '$account' AND branch_id = '-1' AND region_from = '$region_from_id' AND region_to = '$region_to_id' AND restricted = '2' AND restricted_location_id = '$location_to_id' AND CAST('$order_placed_time' AS time) BETWEEN book_from AND book_by")->all();
        }
        if(empty($rates)) {
            // IF THERE IS NO RESTRICTION
            $rates = Rates::find()->where("status_active = 'active' AND master_account = '$account' AND branch_id = '-1' AND region_from = '$region_from_id' AND region_to = '$region_to_id' AND restricted = '0' AND CAST('$order_placed_time' AS time) BETWEEN book_from AND book_by")->all();
        }

        if(empty($rates)) { // IF RESTRICTED IS PICKUP
            $rates = Rates::find()->where("status_active = 'active' AND master_account = '-1' AND branch_id = '-1' AND region_from = '$region_from_id' AND region_to = '$region_to_id' AND restricted = '1' AND restricted_location_id = '$location_from_id' AND CAST('$order_placed_time' AS time) BETWEEN book_from AND book_by")->all();
        }
        if(empty($rates)) { // IF RESTRICTED IS DELIVERY
            $rates = Rates::find()->where("status_active = 'active' AND master_account = '-1' AND branch_id = '-1' AND region_from = '$region_from_id' AND region_to = '$region_to_id' AND restricted = '2' AND restricted_location_id = '$location_to_id' AND CAST('$order_placed_time' AS time) BETWEEN book_from AND book_by")->all();
        }
        if(empty($rates)) {
            // IF THERE IS NO RESTRICTION
            $rates = Rates::find()->where("status_active = 'active' AND master_account = '-1' AND branch_id = '-1' AND region_from = '$region_from_id' AND region_to = '$region_to_id' AND restricted = '0' AND CAST('$order_placed_time' AS time) BETWEEN book_from AND book_by")->all();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It depends on how often the early queries will fail to find something. It might be more efficient to get all the rows that fit the common condition, and then search for the best match in those results in PHP.

Comment: How many rows in the table? Might be better to read them all in one query and then scan them client-side in code. Also prob want to run `EXPLAIN` on your queries to make sure they're adequately indexed.

Comment: You can also use `ORDER BY` to order the results by how well they fit the additional conditions, and `LIMIT 1` so it returns the best one.

Comment: There are 46 rows in the table.

Comment: With only 46 rows in the table, you're almost definitely better off reading them all into the client side and doing the processing there as described above.  The cost of going back and forth to the database is probably a lot higher than the cost of reading in all the rows and doing the logic there.  Plus, then you don't need a complicated SQL query